# What are the various ways to form new subgroups out of existing ones?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group.  Let $A,B,C,\leqslant G, \ \ (A_i)_{i\geq 1} \subset G$ be subgroups.

Then from what I know you can do the following:

$A\cap B$

If $A_i \subset A_{i+1} \forall i$, then: $\cup_i A_i$

$AB  = BA$

Are there any more?

Boris Novikov defines below

$ D_n=\{a\in A|a^n\in B\}$

It too is a group for if $a,b \in D_n$, then $(ab^{-1})^n = a^n (b^{-1})^n = a^n (b^n)^{-1} \in B$  since $B$ is a group.

Let $\oplus$ stand for such an operation, i.e. $D_n = A \oplus B$.  Then it's not necessarily commutative but it does satisfy:
$A\oplus (B \cap C) = (A\oplus B) \cap (A\oplus C)$.

Proof. $A\oplus (B \cap C) = \{ a\in A : a^n \in B \cap C \} = \dots$

Similarly it satisfies $A\cap (B \oplus C) = (A\cap B) \oplus (A\cap C)$.

Proof.  $x \in A\cap (B\oplus C) \implies x \in A\cap B \wedge x^n \in A\cap C$.  Conversely, $x \in RHS \implies x\in A \wedge x\in B \wedge x^n \in C$.

But it's not necessarily associative as

$A\oplus (B \oplus C) = \{ a\in A | a^n \in B \wedge a^{(n^2)} \in C \}$

and $(A\oplus B) \oplus C = \{ a\in A | a^n \in B \wedge a^n \in C \}$.

Comment: But this operation is not associative: $A\oplus(B\oplus C)\ne (A\oplus B)\oplus C)$, so you will not obtain a semiring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a finite abelian group you can do as follows. If $g\in G$ and $H\leqslant G$ then $$|a|_H=\min \{k>0:a^k\in H\}$$ is called the indicator of $a$ in $H$.

Note that $1\leqslant |a|_H\leqslant |a|$ for every $g\in G$, where $|a|$ is the order of $a$. Observe $|a|_H=1\iff a\in H$, and that $|a|_H$ is the order of the coset $aH$ in the quotient $G/H$.

If $H\leqslant G$ and $a\notin H$, let $h=|a|_{H}$ and define $$\langle H,a\rangle =\{xa^k:x\in H\;,\; 0\leqslant k\leqslant h-1\rangle$$

It is readily seen this is a subgroup, and one can prove $$|\langle G',a\rangle |=|a|_{H'}|H|\geqslant |G'|$$ for $a\notin G'$ by assumption.

By starting this construction with $G_0=\{e\}$ one can produce an ascending tower $$G_0\subsetneq G_1\subsetneq G_2\subsetneq \cdots\subsetneq G_r=G$$

of subgroups of $G$. This construction in particular is used to prove every abelian group of order $n$ has exactly $n$ characters.

Comment: Note the indicator is unnecessary to define filtrations of the form $$H\subset \langle H,a\rangle\subset\langle H,a,b\rangle\subset\langle H,a,b,c\rangle\subset\cdots.$$ These indicators are useful however in determining the sucessive indices $[G_{i+1}:G_i]$, or more precisely the isomorphy type of the series' factors (successive quotients) as $G_{i+1}/G_i\cong C_{m_{\large i}}$. Inductively adjoining elements to an algebraic structure is a ubiquitous phenomena in mathematics. In Galois theory these cyclic filtrations are important; it establishes the concept of solvability and Abel-Ruffini.

Answer (score 2):

Since $G$ is abelian, subgroups of $G$ can be considered as $\mathbb{Z}$-submodules of $G$. So one can use various homological constructions. For example, direct limit of a direct system of submodules of $G$  is again a submodule of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

$D_n=\{a\in A|a^n\in B\}$ for fixed $n$.

$E_{m,n}=\{x\in G|x^m\in A,x^n\in B\}$ for fixed $m,n$.

Comment: Letting $D_n = A \oplus B$  There seems to be a semi-ring formed with $\cap$ as multiplication.

Comment: Is $\otimes$ associative?

Comment: It seems to satisfy both $A \oplus (B\cap C) = (A\oplus B)\cap(A\oplus C)$ and $A \cap (B \oplus C) = (A\cap B) \oplus (A \cap C)$

Comment: I asked about associativity, not distributivity.

Comment: I know but isn't it cool that it satisfies that.  It's almost like a set union.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. You define a new operation on subgroups $A\otimes B=\{a\in A|a^n\in B\}$, yes? Or do you consider usual direct sum $\otimes$?

Comment: Please see my edits to my post.